# Executing a Jpype file

Tags: jpype

I am trying to implement a example given in the following tutorial:
[enter link description here](https://hustleplay.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/jpype-tutorial/)

I have been trying to execute this program.However I am stuck on an step which is to "Then place the .class file in the (current_directory)/org/wg3i/test/ directory.".So, when I made a Java file from BlueJ I have the  .class file however I am not sure how I can place that file in (current_directory)/org/wg3i/test/ directory.Also where exactly is this directory located.

Additional Question:

I am trying to implement the following code.

```
import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace;
public class Example2 {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    HeadlessWorkspace workspace =
    HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance() ;
    try {
      workspace.open(
    "models/Sample Models/Earth Science/"
    + "Fire.nlogo");
      workspace.command("set density 62");
      workspace.command("random-seed 0");
      workspace.command("setup");
      workspace.command("repeat 50 [ go ]") ;
      System.out.println(
    workspace.report("burned-trees"));
      workspace.dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

which is given in the following link[enter link description here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API)

However, whenever I try to execute this java code using javac I get an error saying package org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace doesn't exist and also says  HeadlessWorkspace doesn't exist for line 4th.

I know that the link I inserted says this:
In order to compile and run this, NetLogo.jar must be in your classpath. The lib directory, containing additional required libraries, must also be present.

But I am not sure what it exactly asks me to do.

Also, I am working in Linux.

Comment: I understand the tutorial as, that in some folder you have the python code. below that folder you should create a folder hierarchy matching the declaration in the java file, which declares `package org.wg3i.test;` in the beginning. So if your python code is in `/home/foo`, then the class file should be placed inside a folder (you might need to create them before): `/home/foo/org/wg3i/test/` or on windows with some drive letter to the "left" and backslashes ;-) like on drive `d` it could be: `D:\home\foo\org\wg3i\test` - helps a bit? Which platform /operating system? Please add to question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am using Linux system

Comment: Your previous solution worked. Also, I added an additional question today.I'd be obliged if you could help.